# Organizing graph options in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm creating a handful of pie charts using Google Charts. The majority of the graph options for the charts I'm creating are the same, except the titles. Is it possible to maintain a default set of options but write certain specific options for each graph (in this case, I just need to set a title).

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
var graphOptions = {
    is3D: true,
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    colors: ['#F9B641', '#FBCB75', '#FCE1B0', '#FFF8EB', '#FFFFFF'],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#FFF'
    },
    legend: {
        textStyle: {
        color: '#FFF'
        }
    },
    chartArea: {
        width: '90%',
        height: '80%'
    }
};

function pieChart1() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Gender', 'Number'],
        ['Male', 216],
        ['Female', 238]
    ]);
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart1'));
    chart.draw(data, graphOptions);
}

function pieChart2() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Gender', 'Number'],
        ['Male', 116],
        ['Female', 98]
    ]);
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart2'));
    chart.draw(data, graphOptions);
}
```

How would I go about setting the title option for each graph while still pulling the options from graphOptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David explained, you can create an options object, and then edit properties of that object individually.

[Here is a jsfiddle that shows it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/8yqgn/).

<sup>Note: you cannot see the titles because the BG and font color is white. Just do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select everything and see them hidden there</sup>

Basically, you create a variable both functions can access (in your case `graphOptions`). In each function you set a new variable called `options` to equal `graphOptions`. You can then change the `title` property of the `options` variable to whatever you want without changing your default options template `graphOptions`, and use the `options` variable to draw the graph.

For your code, that means adding this code to each function:

```
var options = graphOptions;
options.title = "Pie Chart X"
```

You can change the title to whatever is appropriate, different for each graph. Then in the graph draw command, you change `graphOptions` to `options` to get

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd do:

```
var options = { title: 'My Chat Title' };
```

In your case add title to your graphOptions object then do:

```
graphOptions.title = "The New Title";
```

for each graph.